# How can I change Facebook "Like" button (or perform "Like" action via API)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Facebook has a [great plug-and-play "Like" button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button), which I am using to let a user "Like" my company's official FB page (not an OpenGraph object or something on my company's web site, but http://facebook.com/MyCompanysFacebookPage).

This all works fine, but the "Like" button itself is quite small, so I'd like to replace it with a different graphic. Is this possible? And-- if not-- is it possible to do this "Like" action via the API? (It's fine if I have to ask the user for some kind of special permissions to perform this task, since I am already asking them for other permissions earlier in the UX flow). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if its just a standard "like" button something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/c7rAN/

(it will give you a error until you fill in the fields properly.)

html:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<img src = "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSsRdeyOrORG3mjpsal3tMEzG3hzIl6zkfNnTKm61hJ_h3TL3OQ" id = "share_button">
```

jquery/js

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({appId: 'vvv', status: true, cookie: true,
xfbml: true});
};
(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +
'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#share_button').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
FB.ui(
{
method: 'feed',
name: 'nameit',
link: 'linkit',
picture: 'logo or whatever',
caption: 'caption',
description: 'desscription',
message: 'whatever'
});
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think that makes a "share" button. I'm trying to make a button that performs a "like" on a company page.